# iPhone Strange Settings Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having unexpected results with my application.  I am using a settings bundle, and I want to the default switch to turn on.  The switches are off when I start my application.  But the sound and the shake are working.  I just want the switch to be one when my application loads, and the sound and the shake to be enabled.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Set the application defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"enableSound"];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"enableShake"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults2];
    [defaults synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

Here is part of the code for the sound button:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    enabledSound = [defaults boolForKey:@"enableSound"];
```

Here is part of the code where I dectect the shake:

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    enabledSound = [defaults boolForKey:@"enableSound"];
    enabledShake = [defaults boolForKey:@"enableShake"];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in the settings bundle, that the Value for OFF and the Value for ON should be removed, and the application worked.